# iOS Local notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to trigger local notifications for every 1 minute even in terminated state and background state. But, my app should not trigger notification when time is after 06:00PM. Below is my code.

```
let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60,repeats: true)
    //UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
    // Create the request
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString,
                content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Schedule the request with the system.
    let notificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    notificationCenter.add(request) { (error) in
       if error != nil {
          // Handle any errors.
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle local notification, try this:

```
public func addLocalNotification(hour: Int, minute: Int, identifier: String, title: String, body: String) {
    // Initialize
     let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

   // Set its content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.sound = .default

    // whenever you want to notify user select time
    var dateComp = DateComponents()
    dateComp.calendar = Calendar.current 
    dateComp.hour = hour
    dateComp.minute = minute

    // repeat and date
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComp, repeats: true)

    // Initializing the Notification Request object
    let req = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    // Add the notification to the center
    center.add(req) { (error) in
        if (error) != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what my code do except date operation you did. I'm asking to not to trigger it after 6PM for an instance. i.e. if my app is terminated, I need to do the same.

Comment: Get the time 6 PM, and tell the user notification center to "removeAllPendingNotificationRequests".